# Javascript custom function for array.push and pop

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to create custom functions for JS array functions push, pop, and shift?

For push we can do this

```
var arr = [1,2,3];
Array.prototype.push = function(val){
    var len = this.length;
    this[len] = val;
    return arr;
}
arr.push(5);
```

How we can do pop?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Those are supported since forever, you don't need shims.

Comment: Probably the word shim I have used wrong. I am expecting something like Array.prototype.push = function() to create a custom push functionality. This was an interview question.

Comment: Try then. Loop the arguments and use bracket notation with `i`

Comment: I just told you the answer. If you don't try you'll never learn.

Answer (score 3):

well, you can change the push function's behaviour for all arrays, by change its prototype:

```
js> Array.prototype.push = function() { print('\\_o< quack!'); }
(function () {print("\\_o< quack!");})
js> [].push(1)
\_o< quack!
```

or you can change it for a given instance:

```
js> a = []
[]
js> a.push = function() { print('\\_o< quack!'); }
(function () {print("\\_o< quack!");})
js> b = []
[]
js> a.push(1)
\_o< quack!
js> b.push(1)
1
js> print(b);
1
```

same thing apply for the other methods.

To implement your own pop() method, the general algorithm would be:

```
js> Array.prototype.pop = function() { var ret = this[this.length-1]; this.splice(this.length, 1); return ret }
```

but using splice(), you can actually make it simpler:

```
js> Array.prototype.pop = function() { return this.splice(this.length-1, 1)[0]; }
```

The same approach can be taken for shift:

```
js> Array.prototype.shift = function() { var ret = this[0]; this.splice(0, 1); return ret }
js> Array.prototype.shift = function() { return this.splice(0, 1)[0]; }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you please let me know how we can do POP?

Comment: well if you want to reimplement pop(), you can do: `Array.prototype.pop = function() { var ret = this[this.length-1]; this.splice(this.length-1, 1); return ret }`

Comment: but I don't get what you expected... I mean, you gave the most important hint in your question's comment! The rest is just hacking around the array features...

Comment: I am expecting after do pop I have to get an modified array back.

Comment: Per definition, the [`Array.pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) method removes a value from the array and return that value.

Answer (score 0):

```
var Mainarray=new Array();
var index=0;

    function Push(value){
     Mainarray[index++]=value;
   }
   function Pop(){
     if(index>0){
       index--;
       return Mainarray[index];
     }
      else{
         // display message of Empty Array
       }
   }
```